# What is the proper way to use cross_val_score()

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation

consider a function call like this: `cross_val_score(model, X, y, cv)`. 
Before this function call, I have done training a model with `DecisionTreeClassifier().fit()`, let's call it `trained_model`.

I have these questions:

1. `model`: what should I pass to this parameter? `DecisionTreeClassifier()`, `DecisionTreeClassifier().fit()` or `trained_model`? 
   When I build `trained_model`, I have set `random_state` for the classifier and `train_test_split()`. Should I set `random_state` in `cross_val_score()`?
2. `X, y`: What should I pass to these parameters? `X_train, y_train` or just `X, y`?

Currently my `cross_val_score()` call is like this:
`scores_dtree_cv_kfold = cross_val_score(trained_model, X, y, cv=KFold(5))`
I'm not quite sure what I am doing.

Anyone can tell if I am doing properly or if not, how I am wrong and what will happen?

Comment: Welcome to SO; before rushing to open a question here, please be sure that you have first checked the relevant [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score.html).

Answer (score 0):

Cross-validation is a method to test (not-fitted) model and its parameters.

So, the function requires not-fitted model, (e.g., `cross_val_score(DecisionTreeClassifier())`).

`X, y` should be the whole data, since the function will split them into k-folds.